# AngularJS interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I want to capture all request going out from my one page application like clicking on different tab or any hyperlink.

I have written an interceptor and want to put a ajax call for all request.

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function($q,$http){
    return {
        request: function($http,config){
            window.alert(config.url);               
            var dummyValue = $http.get("url");
            return config;      
        }                       
    }
})
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Do you have a question or is this just a list of requirements?

Comment: Can We place dummy ajax call inside request interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in search of http logger kind of factory. You can use this one

```
.config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {

    // Intercept http calls.
    $provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
        return {
            // On request success
            request: function (config) {
                console.log(config); // Contains the data about the request before it is sent.

                // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            // On request failure
            requestError: function (rejection) {
                console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            // On response success
            response: function (response) {
                console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.

                // Return the response or promise.
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // On response failture
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });

    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider.
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');

});
```

I tested, it works for routeProvider navigation as well. For more information please check this blog  https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

Comment: From front-end you can write logs to console only not to IIS logs. But yes, you are now intercepting every request response and you can make use of these methods to deal with analytical tool.